# Does the Nexus 7 [2013] (Wi-Fi) tablet update to Android 6?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, nexus-7

In my country, Nexus 7 2013 Wifi only tablets are still available. It comes with Android 4.3, but I was told that it updates to 6.0.1 (official update). Does anyone know if this is true? Also, is it stable on 6.0.1? And will Facebook, Instragram, Pintrest & Google Photos apps be stable on it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is true that Nexus 7 [2013] (Wi-Fi) can be updated to official Android 6.0.1. On Google's factory images page for its devices you can see [all the updates](https://developers.google.com/android/images#razor).

The concerned apps work fine with Android 6.0.1, at least on my Nexus 6 with Android 6.0.1.

Comment: Thank you. Do you think it makes sense buying this tablet today? I cannot find any other decent tablet in the price range?

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm not really good on such suggestions and that's off-topic here as well.

Comment: I just found this page https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/6220366?hl=en where it seems to say the Jul 2017 is EOL & Autoupdate won't be available